# Attempted to load class "Spreadsheet" from namespace "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet" - Symnfony4

Tags: symfony4, phpspreadsheet

I have already imported PhpSpreadSheet in my controller.

[image]

I do this for calling the lib :

[image]

The libs is present in my vendor folder.
(PHP 7.3)

Why I have the error below ??

"Attempted to load class "Spreadsheet" from namespace "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet".↵Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace"

Thanks

Comment: sometimes the path must be adapted have you tried the full path? Have you used require 'vendor/autoload.php'; ?

Comment: It work in an other server (WIN),

Comment: Have you tried dumping the autoload / clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes. And nothing to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update symfony flex and it's work.
Thanks for you help.